# What is a good way to begin a search for parameter estimates in a GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-least-squares

Following up on my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307928/81865),  I am wondering

- What is the reasoning for `initialize` expression of the `family` objects in `glm` in R (see `?family`).  `glm` fits generalized linear models and the `initialize` argument is a way to provide initial estimates of the parameters to get an iterative solution started.
- Is it *"good"* way that `glm.fit` start the first iteration be selecting the mean values for each observation? Is there a *"better"* way?

As an example, `binomial()$initialize` selects `mustart <- (weights * y + 0.5)/(weights + 1)` where `weights` (usually) are the number of either cases or controls when you use `glm` with a one dimensional outcome variable.